# How to pass form data to an api GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, postman, form-data

So my backend developer gave me an endpoint to test for `prefill` form data.

So it is a `GET` request `http://localhost:3000/v0/in_progress_forms/MDOT`

and I pass a key/value pair `test:test` in **POSTMAN**

and I get the following response:

```js
{
    "form_data": {
        "profileFullName": {
            "first": "Greg",
            "middle": "A",
            "last": "Anderson"
        },
        "gender": "M",
        "profileAddress": {
            "street": "ADDY 3",
            "city": "Detroit",
            "state": "MI",
            "country": "USA",
            "postalCode": "22312"
        },
        "email": "test2@test1.net",
        "dateOfBirth": "1933-04-05"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "version": 0,
        "prefill": true,
        "returnUrl": "/profile-information"
    }
}
```

So then I setup my api request in React:

```js
export const getUserInformation = formData =>
  apiRequest(`v0/in_progress_forms/MDOT`, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  });
```

Then I just try and test it in my react component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { getUserInformation } from './api';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {  
      getUserInformation().then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          My Component
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default MyComponent;
```

So when I go to the console I see this response:

```js
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3001/mdt/2346/v0/in_progress_forms/MDOT", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3001/mdt/2346/v0/in_progress_forms/MDOT"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

But I am not getting the data as it was from **POSTMAN** How do I structure this to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to keep in mind that you are dealing with the `response` object. A response object will contain some metadata on what was the result of it. For example the HTTP status code, the URL, etc... If you want to get the response data you just need to access the response body:

```
getUserInformation().then(data => {
   if (data.error) {
      console.log(data.error);
   } else {
     //access the response body
     console.log(data.body);
   }
});
```

Comment: There is not data in the body even when I change that.

Comment: Humm, ok. So maybe the issue is that you are sending a JSON but the request is expecting the data to be form-urlencoded. You might want to install a library to do it or you could write your own implementation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are using for sending a request but if you are using the fetch API you need to parse the data first by using `json()` which is another promise and then use it as data

```
getUserInformation().then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

FYI, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a popular promise based HTTP client library for the browser and node.js and already transforms request and response data for you automatically.